# LiveReload LoadError lib/compass/bin/compass

Tags: sass, compass-sass, livereload

Haven't had any trouble with LiveReload until last week, when I must've done something that messed up a path.

Whenever I save a SASS file, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- /Applications/LiveReload.app/Contents/Resources/SASS.lrplugin/lib/compass/bin/compass (LoadError)
```

Indeed, the `lib` directory doesn't even exist. The correct location for compass is in `/Applications/LiveReload.app/Contents/Resources/SASS.lrplugin/gem/bin/compass`

How can I redirect LiveReload to look there? Or better question, what might I have done to mess this up? `gem list` shows up-to-date SASS and compass, and I don't think it's a $PATH problem. I've been using grunt in the meantime, but the LiveReload GUI is less of a hassle. Even suggestions for where to start with this bug would be helpful, as I'm at a loss.

Comment: The same issue has popped up for me in the last week or so. I don't know if it has something to do with a LiveReload update or perhaps the update to Mac OS X 10.9.3. I have a feeling it's a bug in LiveReload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same problem. I upgraded to the latest beta (v2.3.64) and that seems to work.

http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/67441-how-do-i-start-using-livereload-

Answer (score 0):

I does appear to be a bug in the latest version of LiveReload 2.3.62. I restored version 2.3.27 from a backup and that works for me.